# Visual Studio addin - get the solution path the addin is running in

Tags: visual-studio-addins

I am writing a VS addin where it will load some file from the solution the addin is running in. I am wondering how to get the relative path to the solution.

For instance,
I have the application written in :
C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Addins

When I am running the addin in this solution :
D:\dev1\src\

the relative path should be :
D:\dev1\src\

But when I am running the addin in another solution: 
D:\dev2\src\

the relative path will change as well.

How can get the path? Thanks.

Comment: `D:\dev1\src\` would be a full path, not a relative path.

Comment: How to get to the full path, without hard-coding it then?

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this example:

[HOWTO: Get the output build folder from a Visual Studio add-in or macro](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2009/MZ2009015.aspx)